# Compare two differents coordinates in SQL (addition SUM and other)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I wan't to compare two coordinates in my database, but i can't use the addition or subtraction. The database i use is SQLite, on Android.

Here is my SQL request :

```
SELECT m.numMag, nomMag, photoMag, URLMag, latitudeMag,
longitudeMag, numEns, numAdr 
FROM Mag m, Prix p 
WHERE m.numMag=p.numMag AND p.numProduit=1 
AND latitude <= SUM(48.453354+0.01) 
AND latitude >=SUM(48.453354-0.01)
AND longitude <= SUM(2.306644+0.06) 
AND longitude >= SUM(2.306644-0.06);
```

Of course this request is completely wrong, but it's my last test. Somebody can help me ?

Other information : SUM(generated Float, -/+number has already been set)

Comment: Why can't you use addition or subtraction? what is stopping you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUM is an aggregation function, so it works when you have a GROUP BY.  Just remove it . . .

```
SELECT m.numMag, nomMag, photoMag, URLMag, latitudeMag,
       longitudeMag, numEns, numAdr 
FROM Mag m, Prix p 
WHERE m.numMag=p.numMag AND p.numProduit=1 
      AND latitude <= (48.453354+0.01) 
      AND latitude >=(48.453354-0.01)
      AND longitude <= (2.306644+0.06) 
      AND longitude >= (2.306644-0.06);
```

You should also use proper join syntax and you can simplify using between:

```
SELECT m.numMag, nomMag, photoMag, URLMag, latitudeMag,
       longitudeMag, numEns, numAdr 
FROM Mag m join
     Prix p 
     on m.numMag=p.numMag 
WHERE p.numProduit=1 and
      latitude between (48.453354-0.01) and (48.453354+0.01) and
      longitude between (2.306644-0.06) and (2.306644+0.06)
```